# Bind 2 FTP drives into one

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, mount, drive

Mounting an FTP drive can be easily be done with `curlftpfs` in Ubuntu 10.

Also, there would be no problem to mount two or more drives. e.g.

```
/var/ftpdrive1/ 
/var/ftpdrive2/
```

**Question**: is there a way to bind `/var/ftpdrive1/` and `/var/ftpdrive2/` to `/var/ftpdrive0/`.

...make two drives act as one ?

Answer (score 2):

Have not tried with FTP mounts, but [UnionFS](http://www.filesystems.org/project-unionfs.html) (works with Linux and FreeBSD at least) allows you to merge several mount points as one, yet keeping the physical data separate.

Comment: Do not use unionfs on FreeBSD up to 12.1 and possibly later, it can cause kernel panics and security issues. See the BUGS section of `man 8 mount_unionfs` for more scary details.

Answer (score 1):

No. What do you think happens when you have two files with the same name on both servers? Which one should be displayed? And if you store a file, where should it be saved, on server 1 or server 2?

Answer (score -1):

You could use NFS to export /var/ftpdrive1/ and /var/ftpdrive2/.  Then mount them as such:

```
/var/ftpdrive0/1 and /var/ftpdrive0/2
```

Would this work?  Two drives would act as one, with two subdirectories.

Comment: Since you can mount an FTP dir via `curlftps`, all you managed to do is to rename the directories and move the problem from FTP to NFS.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I am not very familiar with curlftps.  Thanks for the insight.